# Typo in tour. "/li>"

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-tour

There is a typo in [the tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour).

[image]

"/li>" shouldn't be there.

Comment: I just saw this, too. Nice catch.

Comment: That was my bad. I didn't correctly close that tag when I was editing the tour. I've fixed it now.